# `hbase.rootdir` configuration from job setup not honoured

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I was running map reduce jobs on HDFS, on data present in hbase tables. WHile I was playing with configurations, I observed this.

```
conf.set( "hbase.rootdir", "hdfs://" + hdfsRootNodeIp + ":" + hdfsRootPort + "/" + hbaseDirectoryName );
```

For the above code, I understand that `hbaseDirectoryName` should be the folder created on HDFS. I have created `/hbase` directory, and jobs are running fine.
While I tried with some junk names during MR job setup, even then map-reduce jobs went through successfully, without throwing an error.

Can somebody explain the behaviour for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hbase.rootdir` is not a client side property. Its a server side(Region Server) property. Hence, setting it from your MapReduce job doesnt have any impact at all.

Comment: Oh thanks a ton Anil Gupta. I did not know that. So is there a differentiation between client side and server side properties? Where can I find some docs on that?

Comment: I am not aware of any naming convention for client vs server properties. Usually, properties related to Scan, Get, Delete, and some HTable properties are client side. Most of the RegionServer properties are server side.